# Оператор switch ругается на значение в вызваном из класса конструкторе

Tags: c++, строки, классы, конструктор, switch

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "product.h"
#include "string"
#include "day.h"
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int Show;
    double bel;
    double ygl;
    double gur;
    double kkal;
    char data;
    std::string name;
    ofstream fout;
    ifstream fin;
    cin >> Show;

    switch (Show)
    {
        case 1:
            name = " ";
            cout << "Введите имя продукта: ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Введите количество белков: ";
            cin >> bel;
            cout << "Введите количество углеводов: ";
            cin >> ygl;
            cout << "Введите количество жира";
            cin >> gur;
            product name(bel, ygl, gur, name);
            ** ругается на этот нейм**
            fout.open("product.txt", std::ios::app);
            fout << name;
            break;
            fout.close();

        case 2:
            ....
```

компилятор выдает

передача управления в обход инициализации: переменная (name) 
этот конструктор выглядит так:

```
product(double bel, double ygl, double gur, std::string name)
{
    Belok= bel;
    Yglevod= ygl;
    Gur= gur;
    Kkal= (bel*4)+(ygl*4)+(gur*9);
    Name= name;
}
```

`name` пробовал заполнять через `getline(cin,name)`, через `cin>>name`, через `cin.get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотя данное предложении корректное

```
product name(bel,ygl,gur, name);
        ^^^^              ^^^^
```

с точки зрения использования одного и того же имени для двух сущностей, так как в этом предложении имя `name`, используемое в качестве аргумента, относится к объекту `std::string`, тем не менее такое предложение может вводить в заблуждение читающих ваш код.

Используйте другое имя для объекта класса.

С другой стороны, определение объекта класса, который имеет не тривиальный конструктор, некорректно, так как управление может быть передано на другую метку, минуя это определение. Вам следует заключить эти предложения в составное предложение, как, например,

```
case 1:
{
    //...
}
```

Имейте в виду, что область объявления этого объекта, это либо тело оператора `switch`, либо блок кода, если таковой используется с меткой. Вне оператора он не будет виден.

Comment: а если я указываю 
name(..,..,.., (std::string)name);
так же ошибку выдает.

Comment: Сделал. проблема была в 
    case 1:
    {

    } cпасибо

Comment: @Макс  Я был не прав по поводу того, что имя объекта класса скрывает имя объекта, который используется в качестве аргумента. Я подправил свое сообщение. В сущности, оно осталось тем же самым, так как указывает на причину ошибки. Не забывайте про область объявления переменной объекта.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
product name(bel,ygl,gur, name);
```

Что вы хотите сделать? Создать `name`? Но он же уже есть, и имеет тип `string` :) Может, для начала используете другое имя для переменной типа `product`?

Далее, вы точно не забыли `break` перед `case 2`?

И еще - я бы взял код в `case 1` в фигурные скобки - чтоб не поднимать вопрос с инициализацией и передачей управления...